# Can anyone simplify / optimize the code in Excel/VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

It is a simple code I got from running a macro but it takes a long time to process. Can anyone who's good at vba fix this please?
Thanks.

```
Sub ClearAll()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("H2:H11").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A2:A100").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.ClearFormats
    Sheets(2).Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Delete
    Sheets(1).Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: (Bursts out in tears.)

Comment: `Can anyone who's good at vba fix this please?` I am not good in VBA but I can point you in the [Right Direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) Please try and incorporate the suggestions. If you are still stuck then post the new code

Comment: How was your last 23 days with Excel and VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat better...

```
Sub ClearAll()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("H2:H11").ClearContents
    With Range("A2:A100")
        .ClearContents
        .ClearFormats
    End With
    Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets(3).Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Delete
    Sheets(1).UsedRange.Select
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, I have seen people do this before. Is there a point to your second with statement? You only use it once. Why not just use `Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents`?

Comment: Nah... you're right. I put it because when I started correcting the code, I thought there would be more statements coming... it's superfluous.

Comment: Updated based on your comment